# Put a small image on a panning-image background

Tags: html, css, image

I have a panning image inside a div. On this panning image, that is a background, I have a html map area with some link to other pages. This works.
Anyway, now I want to put a small image on this panning background. I've tried with the css "position:relative" and it works.. but the link in the map area aren't clickable yet. If I remove the "position:relative" in the panning image, link works. How can i fix this? I need that link works.. but I want the image on the panning-image(in background) too.

```
<img src='/images/mappa/atlas.jpg' class='panning' usemap="#Map" style="position:relative!important;z-index:-1000!important;">

   <map name="Map" id="Map">
   <area alt="Arena" title="Arena" href="/script/chat.php?luogo=Arena" shape="rect" coords="513,434,531,452"/>
   <area alt="Isola Inesplorata" title="Isola Inesplorata" href="/script/chat.php?luogo=Isola_Inesplorata" coords="204,77,12" shape="circle">
   </map>

<img src="/images/minions/8.png" style="margin-top:<?php echo $y;?>;margin-left:<?php echo $x;?>;position:relative!important;z-index:-700!important;">
```

Obviously the map code is much longer, I just put the necessary for the example. I have already tried to move the code of the small image above or below the panning-background, it is irrelevant.

I put the css directly in the style to make you better understand what I entered.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used this solution:

1) I've created a new div container with position relative and z-index that have a negative value (ex: -1000).
2) I've setted to the small image the z-index with a POSITIVE value and the position relative.

Now I've got the image and the links.